# Javascript huge date bug in windows... Solutions?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, date, internet-explorer-8

My dev environment is in mac.

I use bootstrap datepicker to choose dates in an application.

When a day like `27/11/2013` is selected in mac when I debug, the screen shows...

```
day: 1385510400
```

and the translation to an date object in the same debug tool is,

```
 Wed Nov 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

which is correct.

All is OK, since here.

I upload the code to a windows environment and open the same page with IE8.

Start the nightmare... :)

**In windows**, the same day variable is shown like that...

```
day: 1385506800
```

and the translation to an date object in the same debug tool is,

```
 Wed Nov 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

which, is not correct?

If we go to a external tool, the day that gave IE8 is day before, and the translation should be,

```
 Tue, 26 Nov 2013 23:00:00 GMT.
```

How I can understand this?

There is no relation with the timestamp and the translation to date object, and obviously I can't find a way to make this works in both systems.

Could you wake me up from this nightmare?

Sorry for my english!

Comment: Always assume you are doing something wrong before shouting BUG

Comment: When I see Wed 27 00:00:00 UTC+0000 2013 that comes from 1385506800 timestamp... there is no logic mistake, that is wrong! Works fine in other browsers, IE8 is the problem.

Comment: 1385510400 and 1385506800 both work out to a time on Jan 17 **1970**.

Comment: 1385506800 = Tue, 26 Nov 2013 23:00:00 GMT (from http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

Comment: That website is "based on seconds since standard epoch of 1/1/1970", but JS dates are based on _milliseconds_ since 1/1/1970. How about you actually show the JS code you are using so that we can see exactly how you get 1385510400?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MD9s6/show)

In JS in Chrome:

```
new Date(1385510400000) : Wed Nov 27 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0100    
new Date(1385506800000) : Wed Nov 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date("11/27/2013")  : Wed Nov 27 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Please note the order of the date string, it is in US order
Also note the 000 at the end; JS timestamps are in milliseconds

The same in IE8

```
Wed Nov 27 01:00:00 UTC+0100 2013
Wed Nov 27 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013
Wed Nov 27 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013
```

So exactly the same dates, on hour difference on the first

If you subtract the 1 hour from all dates, you get midnight on the first and 11pm on the 26th on the rest

To normalise you can do

```
var d = new Date(1385510400000);
d.setHours(0,0,0);
```

or change to UTC